# Is it possible to run silverlight and visual c sharp windows forms as a single application

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I want to develop an application that supports the web operations as well as the serial port and Tcp operations .Which platform to use ?

Or is it possible to add the application as a reference to other?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please read [faq] and [ask] before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

My default answer here would be "no". You might be able to develop much of it as a "Portable Class Library" that targets .NET Framework and Silverlight, but I suspect you'll find all the things you want to do aren't included in the intersection between .NET Framework and Silverlight.

The entire purpose of a "Portable Class Library" is that it can indeed by added as a reference from multiple frameworks, but the restriction is that you are limited to the *strict intersection* - i.e. the functionality that exists in **all** the frameworks that you select in the PCL target frameworks. The more target frameworks you add, the smaller the intersection will generally become. You will not be able to use a PCL to magically add winforms-specific functionality to a Silverlight application, or add Silverlight-specific functionality to a winform.

Comment: Thanks Marc..Is there any way to develop such applications??